# What is the logic of approximate string matching?

Tags: r, agrep, approximate

Does anybody know what is the reason for the following example:

```
agrepl("cold", "cool")
#> [1] FALSE
agrepl("cool", "cold")
#> [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Also, you may be interested in the methods used in the `stringdist` package

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the `max distance` defaults to:

> If cost is not given, all defaults to 10%, and the other transformation number bounds default to all. The component names can be abbreviated.

And:

> Expressed either as integer, or as a fraction of the pattern length times the maximal transformation cost (will be replaced by the smallest integer not less than the corresponding fraction)

The default maximum amount of transformations for a pattern of length 4 is 1. 
The `cool`-pattern matches the `col` in the beginning of the `cold` using only 1 deletion. Changing the `cold` to match `cool` would take at least two transformations (two subsitutions or one deletion and one insertion).

These examples might explain it a bit further:

```r
agrepl("cold", "cool",max.distance = 1) # two changes necessary
#> [1] FALSE
agrepl("cold", "cool",max.distance = 2)
#> [1] TRUE
agrepl("cold", "coold") # just one addition necessary
#> [1] TRUE
```