# Agrepl - what does a 10% threshold mean?

Tags: r, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy-comparison

I used Agrepl for fuzzy matching between two sets of addresses. The [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/agrep.html) says that the default is:

> If cost is not given, all defaults to 10%, and the other
> transformation number bounds default to all. The component names can
> be abbreviated.

However, [reading this q&a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60452957/what-is-the-logic-of-approximate-string-matching/60453251#60453251) with this example, that doesn't seem to match up. Here is that example:

```
agrepl("cold", "cool")
#> [1] FALSE
agrepl("cool", "cold")
#> [1] TRUE
```

From the description, I'd imagine that calculating the 10% would be having 1 change in a 10 letter word, but this is 1 in 4. How exactly is this calculated?

Answer (score 0):

This is admittedly very confusing (at least to me!), but here's my attempt to explain it. The [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60452957/what-is-the-logic-of-approximate-string-matching/60453251#60453251) says:

> The default maximum amount of transformations for a pattern of length 4 is 1.

How do we get from 0.1 (cost) × 4 (pattern length) to 1? Well, `?agrepl` notes that the `max.dist` is expressed as

> as a fraction of the *pattern* length times
> the maximal transformation cost (**will be replaced by the
> smallest integer not less than the corresponding fraction**)

(emphasis added); I take the parenthetical clause to mean that the maximum number of transformations is `ceiling(0.1*4)` = 1. We would need a pattern with length ≥ 11 in order for `ceiling(0.1*pattern_length)` to increase from 1 to 2 ...

If you want to find out where this is actually implemented, you have to dig fairly deep into the C source code, i.e. [lines 59-60 of agrep.c](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/6b22b60126646714e0f25143ac679240be251dbe/src/main/agrep.c#L59-L60), in the `amatch_regparams` function, where we see

```c
if(bound < 1) bound *= (patlen * max_cost);
params->max_cost = IntegerFromReal(ceil(bound), &warn);
```

Comment: Follow up question, maybe better for cross validated (but not sure)... If I want to use this and the default setting for doing fuzzy matching, and I write that up in my methods, is there any text I can point to to say, look this strategy is reasonable? After I did this I spot checked the data with a random sample, but my advisor is looking for something more when I'm explaining it.

Comment: I have no idea. Maybe ask on the `r-help@r-project.org` mailing list ... ????  This might be the original author ... https://www.technikum-wien.at/en/staff/david-meyer/